# Django path converter raises SynchronousOnlyOperation

Tags: django, python-asyncio, django-orm, asgi

I'm migrating an existing WSGI server to ASGI and I'm running into a problem where ORM usage in path converters raises a SynchronousOnlyOperation exception.

My converter code is something like this

```py
class ModelPkConverter:
    regex = r'\d+'
    model = MyModel

    def to_python(self, primary_key):
        try:
            return self.model.objects.get(pk=primary_key)
        except self.model.DoesNotExist:
            raise ValueError

    def to_url(self, instance):
        return f'{instance.pk}'
```

So when I go to a URL like `/myapp/<MyModel:my_model>/` I get

> django.core.exceptions.SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.

Where exactly am I supposed to put `sync_to_async`? If I do it in the converter like this

```py
    @sync_to_async
    def to_python(self, primary_key):
        ...
```

The converter outputs a coroutine object instead of a MyModel instance so I get AttributeError when I attempt to use it.

> AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'my_attribute'

Am I supposed to `await` it in the view? That would defeat the purpose of using converters. I can just do `get_object_or_404` instead.

Is there a solution that doesn't involve setting `DJANGO_ALLOW_ASYNC_UNSAFE` to True?
At this point, I'm considering refactoring everything away from the converters and using `<int:mymodel_id>` everywhere instead. Is there another way?

Comment: I am not sure whether this can be made to work, but the approach is kinda weird. I would recommend against it, the converters are probably only designed to handle simple operations like string parsing. So I would go with `get_object_or_404`

Comment: That seems to be the way to go. I'll move away from using converters this way. Thanks.